# Resolve shift/reduce conflict in Bison for dot separated items

Tags: c++, grammar, bison, yacc

I am making an interpreter for a language in which everything is expressions. It supports constructs we can named dot separated expressions. `EXPR . EXPR . EXPR`
The grammar rule for expr is:

```
expr:
    INTEGER | DOUBLE
    | ... SOME OTHER EXPR'S
    | expressions_dot                 { printf("Dot expression"); }
    ;
expressions_dot:
    DOT expr %prec DOT
    | expressions_dot DOT expr %prec DOT { printf("dot separated expression\n"); }
    ;
```

Before the introduction of this rule, I had no conflicts, but after its appearance, exactly one conflict appears. The whole point is that I need to parse from left to right, then it will be convenient to create a vector for a structure of the Node* type, which stores the tree. `expressions_dot` has highest priority `%left DOT`.

The `y.output` log file shows that will be not a problems with it, but my sense of a perfectionist does not let me calm down and I cant sleep.

```
state 28

   13 expr: expressions_dot .
   44 expressions_dot: expressions_dot . DOT expr

    DOT  shift, and go to state 55

    DOT       [reduce using rule 13 (expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 13 (expr)
```

Is it possible to resolve this conflict without right-to-left rule? Or some trick to use additional rule?

**UPD:** main thing I cant understand why Bison want to reduce??

Comment: Not sure of the expected grammar, do you want `EXPR (DOT EXPR)*` (list of EXPR separated by DOT) or can we have `DOT DOT EXPR DOT DOT` (`DOT` works "as" parenthesis but no difference between open and close one).

Comment: @Jarod42 the first one, expr (DOT expr)*. Later it should be used in 3 rules: expr expressions_dot, DOT expr expressions_dot, DOT DOT expr expressions_dot. For different contexts. So expressions_dot rule is using to make special helpful vector of Nodes, which will be better for program tree.

Comment: So you should already have solved the issue with that kind of list for sum, something like `expr_leaf: DOUBLE | INT; expr: expr_leaf dot_expr; dot_expr: empty | DOT expr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 why? I dont think so, because dot_expr cant be empty in my grammar.

Comment: Here, my `dot_expr` is just an helper, rename it if you want. Which is the difference between `expr` and `expressions_dot`? `42 . 42 . 42` is both as I understand. (as `42` and `42+42+42` are both valid sum).

Comment: @Jarod42 the difference is that for 42 + 42 you have left and right Node, then 42 + 42 + 42 you have left Node as 42 + 42 and right Node as 42. With 42 . 42 . 42 you should collect vector of Nodes for . 42 . 42 first, and then you can apply it to 42 or .42 or ..42.

Comment: Isn't what `expr: expr_leaf dot_expr;` does? `dot_expr` is the vector, `expr_leaf` is the node to apply it (if not empty).

Comment: @jarod42 for example you have variable $a and you can get this variable attributes like $a.aa.aaa. You should know which attribute going first, you should get b = $a.aa value first, then b.aaa value. This is easy to do when you have vector of attributes from left to right.

Comment: @Jarod42 dot_expr include nothing, this is not good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225412/discussion-between-jarod42-and-evgeny).